# Generic Repository Extending: Inheritance vs. Extension Methods

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, extension-methods, repository-pattern

I am planning to use Generic Repository in my entity framework project. But which is better for extending the repository for the operations which the base generic repository does not include.

**Inheritance:**

```
public class CustomerRepository:Repository<Customer>
{
    public decimal GetCustomerOrderTotalByYear(int customerId, int year)
    {
        return base
            .FindById(customerId)
            .Orders.SelectMany(o => o.OrderDetails)
            .Select(o => o.Quantity*o.UnitPrice).Sum();
    }
}
```

**Extension Methods:**

```
public static class CustomerRepositoryExtensions
{
    public static decimal GetCustomerOrderTotalByYear(this Repository<Customer> customerRepository, int customerId, int year)
    {
        return customerRepository
            .FindById(customerId)
            .Orders.SelectMany(o => o.OrderDetails)
            .Select(o => o.Quantity*o.UnitPrice).Sum();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would be in favor of the Inheritance approach since the query is specific to the CustomerRepository class. One question. Why is the CustomerRepository class static?

Comment: Again in the extension style; it is also being specific to Repository<Customer>. And I removed the static in the first class, it was written by mistake.

Comment: The thing with the Extension method is that you would need to include the namespace everywhere you plan to use the extension method. With the inheritance approach you would get access to the method for free with the repository object.

Comment: It is PERFECTLY OKAY to create a concrete repository when a generic implementation wont all you need it too.  However, the ONLY time I would use an extension method is when you have no control over the implementation being "served-up".  At the moment, I have EXACTLY that situation - the version being served-up has abstract properties & there is no way for me to see "under the hood" (yet).  So, yes...do it.

Comment: A drawback implementing Extensions is when you need to deal with multiple tables, like joins, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Don't create query methods on repository. Use repositories to maintain aggregate consistency not for generic querying. Otherwise your interface is very bloated and your repositories just end up a dumping ground for a myriad of different queries. Just create queries and query handlers. I only use repository for getting data out that I am going to update.

Do something like [this](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92).

This is a  far more [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) approach.

Comment: An addendum: a query handler isn't a substitute for repository, a handler can use a repository. While in DDD a repository is used only for domain purposes, the repository pattern is unrelated to DDD and it can be used outside the domain with the same purpose: to abstract persistence and deocuple an app object from its persistence form. Personally, my query handlers use specialized query repositories (interfaces of course) because I don't want my DAL to know about my view models. In my case, the query handler acts as bridge between persistence and the view model.

Comment: Agreed. However most people are using ORM and to performance tune your queries via repository without just having many methods on the interface(which is never great). Each query needs the right includes, projections etc.  For most systems I've done I query against the ORM directly. I tend to find I query ORM convert then to viewmodel via Automapper in query. Then if you need more performance denormalize to a fast store and have your query just return persistent viewmodel. If you have a query and handler - you already have an abstraction hiding your datalayer. Its all trade offs though :)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with inheritance.

Extension methods are appropriate, in my opinion, when you want to add functionality to a class you have no control over (For example String extensions) or when you want to provide functionality for an interface that should do the same thing no matter which implementation you are currently working with (For example LINQ is a set of extensions for IEnumerable)

In this case, it makes sense to say "This is my CustomerRepository, and the CustomerRepository has some extra stuff or does some stuff a little differently from the default behavior, but at the end of the day a Customer repository *is* a Repository.

Mind you, this is all rather subjective and based on personal preference, but my vote goes toward the inheritance route.

Answer (score 0):

I have typically gone the inheritance route. This looked very similar to what you poasted. I have a Generic "base" repository implementation into which the IUnitOfWork is injected. Then in each of my BaseRepository inheriting classes, I would implement my queries. Here is an older post I made with an older version of this "pattern": https://stackoverflow.com/a/18788895/1426342

This method always seemed the most straightforward to me, and was easier to explain to my clients when I was handing off code. It was easier to follow the execution path from front to back. However with larger systems it gets pretty messy! It also couples your context implementation to your repository. I've since made a couple additional to pass the context type in as a generic which helps with that, and allows me to have multiple context implementations which I can post if you like.

Recently however, having been challenged by a colleague to further break it down and decouple Entity Framework from my repository implementation I have tried the second method you posted. And to be honest, I think I might prefer this method going forward. It seems a little more lightweight to me as you aren't injecting all those different "repository" methods which honestly don't really even need to be injected. Take a look at this guys blog for a really good example of this implementation: http://blog.longle.net/2013/05/11/genericizing-the-unit-of-work-pattern-repository-pattern-with-entity-framework-in-mvc

After examining that more closely I think you will come to agree. The extensions methods are a more performant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but I would just like to add one point when I find extensions more suitable - when you resolve your dependencies via DI container and you have *a lot* of `Repositories`. In this case you only have to register your generic repo, not each one individually.